# How to generate extra files with the command python manage.py startapp xxx?

Tags: django, python-3.x

There is some way for the "python manage.py createapp xxx" command to generate some extra files like, e.g. `xxx.urls`, `statics.dir`, `template.dir`, etc.

I would like to be able to avoid the work of having to generate the files and directories that I might need later. files as for example; `app.urls`, `statics.dir`, etc

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own Django commands. Example:

```
python manage.py execute_my_command
```

The structure of your folders should be similar. The project will be called test and the structure will be the following:

```
test
   management
      commands
           __init__.py
           execute_python.py
      __init__.py
```

Within our project tests is the folder management, within these commands and within command our python file, which has the name of the command to be performed. Inside execute_python is where the command code will be:

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
help = "Ejecuta archivo python archivo_a_ejecutar.py"

def handle(self, *args, **options):
    self.stdout.write('Ejecutando comando')
    os.system("python archivo_a_ejecutar.py")
```

Answer (score 0):

The [**`startapp`** command [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startapp) has a **`--template` flag**. As the documentation says:

> **`--template TEMPLATE`**
>
> Provides the path to a directory with a custom app template file or a
>   path to a compressed file (`.tar.gz`, `.tar.bz2`, `.tgz`, `.tbz`,
>   `.zip`) containing the app template files.

For example [`joshvillbrandt/django-quick-start-app` [GitHub]](https://github.com/joshvillbrandt/django-quick-start-app) contains such template. You can fetch a zipped copy with `https://github.com/joshvillbrandt/django-quick-start-app/archive/master.zip`. This repository contains, as you can see, a `templates` and `static` directory, as well as an `urls.py`, `views.py`, `tests.py`, `admin.py`, etc.

So you can run the `startapp` command with:

```
manage.py startapp --template 'https://github.com/joshvillbrandt/django-quick-start-app/archive/master.zip' myappname
```

You can of course look for another repository that contains a template. Furthermore you can define your own template that contains an app the way you like it.